# How to store values in an Array after every iteration?

Tags: java, arrays

Consider the scenario below:

```
Public Class A {
.....
 static void DoSomething(){
  int a=some mathematical operation;
  int b[10];
  }
 }

Public Class B{
....
public static void main(String[] args)
{
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
 A.DoSomething; 
 }
 }
}
```

Here the mathematical operation in Class A is being executed over a forloop in the main program, what I want to achieve is that I want to store the value of variable being calculated in Class A after every iteration into Array b. 
In the end I want my output to look like this:

```
b[10]=[iteration1value iteration2value......iteration10value]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a return type to `DoSomething()` and return the value:

```
Public Class A {
    .....
    public static int DoSomething(){
        int a = someMathematicalOperation();
        return a;    
    }
}
```

Create the `b` array here and update the value as you loop.

```
Public Class B{
    ....
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] b = new int[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            b[i] = A.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why but this gives me a null pointer exception.

Comment: Where does it give you that?  Which line? Can you edit in your updated code in the opening post?

Comment: Well it is solved now, I used your logic but used ArrayLists instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have outlined the correct structure. What makes the most sense to me is

```
1) Class A has non-static, private  function called "doSomething()" which returns a result. 
2) Class B has a non-static variable which holds the array. 
3) In "main", instantiate both class A and class B.
4) Still in main, call a.doSomething() to retrieve the result of the operation.
5) Take the result of the operation and put it into the array held by B.
```